# Beautiful soup not finding any elements under a class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape the prices of a website using BeautifulSoup:

The container class is shown below:

[image]

An example of the objects I want to retrieve from that class are shown below:
[image]

[image]

But I don't know why there are no objects being found under the containing class `c1_t2i`. It always prints a value of 0 in the `print(len(containers))`

The code is shown below:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myUrl = "https://www.lazada.com.ph/catalog/?q=lighters&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2o4l.home.search.go.239e6ef0RMwbfH"

uClient = uReq(myUrl)
pageHtml = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
pageSoup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
containers = pageSoup.findAll("div", {"class": "c1_t2i"})
print(len(containers))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the page, and view page source. You won't be able to find the class "`c1_t2i`". The class you are looking for seems to be "`c3e8SH`".

I am however, not sure why this is happening. I am using chrome. Can you use chrome and check perhaps? You can also print out the parsed HTML, and search for the text "`c1_t2i`" or "`c3e8SH`", whichever is available there.

**EDIT 1:**

I think I understand the problem. The HTML you see when you do inspect element are generated using Javascript. However, the same classes are not available in the raw html that you get using the script. You need to use something like PhantomJS to execute the JS and get the resulting HTML. Check out [this](https://www.quora.com/Can-beautifulsoup-scrape-javascript-rendered-webpages) thread.

**EDIT 2:**

You can also try to disable JS and look at the page that comes up, and then see if you can select a class name from the basic HTML.

Comment: I see both `c1_t2i` and `c3e8SH` in the page source. Each item has it's own `c3e8SH` class. But the one containing all of the items I believe is `c1_t2i`? I don't have chrome in this computer to check, but I use chrome at my home pc and it still shows the same code I believe.

Comment: That's surprising. When I go to view page source, and find `c1_t2i`. I get zero results. Can you try and check if you get any objects using the classname `c3e8SH`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried replacing `c1_t2i` with `c3e8SH` to get `containers = pageSoup.findAll("div", {"class": "c3e8SH"})` and I get 0 as well

Comment: Thank you i'll check it out

Comment: Added another tip. This might help.

Comment: I asked a person to program the web scraping script. She used the `json` library and then made use of proxies before scrapping. Also `PhantomJS` is already discontinued upon checking